# Match multiple strings containing lines from file python

Tags: python

I want to match multiple strings from a file. How do I do this in python ?

**Objective:** match the lines which is having both values of "DC1" & "TIER2" from file

---

My code but give matches any string from strings object

```
strings = ["DC1","TIER2"]
with open(r"D:\kick-6.log", "r" ) as data:
    for deltaa in data:
        deltaa = data.readline().rstrip()
        print ("*********")
        for item in strings:
            if item in deltaa:
                print (deltaa)
```

Comment: You'd post the contents of *kick-6.log*.

Comment: You probably just want `deltaa = deltaa.rstrip()` on the fourth line.

Comment: Yes . tried and it's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) for your checking:

> `all(iterable)` Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or
>   if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

```
strings = ["DC1","TIER2"]
with open(r"D:\kick-6.log", "r" ) as data:
    for deltaa in data:
        if all(x in deltaa for x in strings): #Check if all items in strings exit in deltaa
            print (deltaa)
```

And if you want to check if at least one of `strings` is in `deltaa` use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#any) instead:

> `any(iterable)` Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If
>   the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

```
strings = ["DC1","TIER2"]
with open(r"D:\kick-6.log", "r" ) as data:
    for deltaa in data:
        if any(x in deltaa for x in strings): #Check if any item in strings exits in deltaa
            print (deltaa)
```

Comment: @veejay .. Feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer

Comment: if i want to print only non matched strings from the above example what to do?

Comment: @veejay...you mean printing lines from file that *do not match* with `strings` ?